# How to get next node by condition in xsl?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

For example, there is a XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <row>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <WeaNr_ArtNr>100027</WeaNr_ArtNr>
        <UID>101114557945</UID>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Type>2</Type>
        <WeaNr_ArtNr>2000311</WeaNr_ArtNr>
        <UID>101114557945</UID>
        <UnitQuantity>10</UnitQuantity>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <WeaNr_ArtNr>100027</WeaNr_ArtNr>
        <UID>101114557946</UID>
    </row>
<row>
    <Type>2</Type>
    <WeaNr_ArtNr>2000312</WeaNr_ArtNr>
    <UID>101114557946</UID>
    <UnitQuantity>10</UnitQuantity>
</row>
    <row>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <WeaNr_ArtNr>55555</WeaNr_ArtNr>
        <UID>101114558000</UID>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Type>2</Type>
        <WeaNr_ArtNr>200053155555</WeaNr_ArtNr>
        <UID>101114558000</UID>
        <UnitQuantity>1</UnitQuantity>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <WeaNr_ArtNr>55555</WeaNr_ArtNr>
        <UID>101114558001</UID>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Type>2</Type>
        <WeaNr_ArtNr>200053255555</WeaNr_ArtNr>
        <UID>101114558001</UID>
        <UnitQuantity>1</UnitQuantity>
    </row>
        <row>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <WeaNr_ArtNr>100023</WeaNr_ArtNr>
        <UID>101114557989</UID>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Type>2</Type>
        <WeaNr_ArtNr>2000274</WeaNr_ArtNr>
        <UID>101114557989</UID>
        <UnitQuantity>14</UnitQuantity>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <WeaNr_ArtNr>100023</WeaNr_ArtNr>
        <UID>101114557990</UID>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Type>2</Type>
        <WeaNr_ArtNr>2000275</WeaNr_ArtNr>
        <UID>101114557990</UID>
        <UnitQuantity>23</UnitQuantity>
    </row>
</root>
```

By knowing `WeaNr_ArtNr` value for case `Type='1'` I want to return next node

for example, for `WeaNr_ArtNr='100027`' I want to get these nodes:

```
<row>
    <Type>2</Type>
    <WeaNr_ArtNr>2000311</WeaNr_ArtNr>
    <UID>101114557945</UID>
    <UnitQuantity>10</UnitQuantity>
</row>
<row>
    <Type>2</Type>
    <WeaNr_ArtNr>2000312</WeaNr_ArtNr>
    <UID>101114557946</UID>
    <UnitQuantity>10</UnitQuantity>
</row>
```

because these nodes are going after node when `WeaNr_ArtNr='100027'`

I've tried something like this

```
/root/row[WeaNr_ArtNr='100023']/preceding::row[WeaNr_ArtNr!='100023']
```

but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the row immediately following each row that has `WeaNr_ArtNr='100027'`?  Then how about

```
/root/row[WeaNr_ArtNr='100027']/following-sibling::row[1]
```